# Error al buscar la url en el servidor

Tags: php, mvc

estoy empezando a trabajar con MVC, luego del login, estoy tratando de redirigirme a mi pagina de Inicio con un window.location, pero al momento de mandarle el modulo inicio me aparece el error Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this
server.

Pero si le pongo la ruta completa si me llama la pagina.

Mi controlador:

```
class UserC{

public function LoginC(){

if(isset($_POST["usuario"])){

  $tableDB = "usuario";

  $dataC = array("usuario" => $_POST["usuario"], "clave" => $_POST["clave"]);

  $result = UserM::LoginM($tableDB, $dataC);

  if($result["usuario"] == $_POST["usuario"] && $result["clave"] == $_POST["clave"]){

    $_SESSION["Login"] = true;

    $_SESSION["id"] = $result["id"];
    $_SESSION["nombre"] = $result["nombre"];
    $_SESSION["apellido"] = $result["apellido"];
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $result["usuario"];
    $_SESSION["clave"] = $result["clave"];
    $_SESSION["token"] = $result["token"];
    $_SESSION["rol"] = $result["rol"];
    $_SESSION["correo"] = $result["correo"];

    echo '<script>

      window.location = "Inicio";<-- Llamandolo asi me da el error.
      window.location = "View/modulos/Inicio" <-- Llamandolo asi si me redirige
    </script>';

  }else{

    echo '<br><div class="alert alert-danger">Usuario o Contraseña erroneo</div>';
  }

}

}

}
```

Mi .htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo, o de donde guiarme para hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tienes en que la parte de 'View/modulos/' no deberías esperar que venga en el parámetro url, sino que a todo lo que te venga como url deberías anteponerle eso. Porque la redirección para 'Inicio' seguro que te está funcionando. Otra cosa, si al momento de la redirección aún no has pintado nada, hazla mejor desde PHP con header('Location: ...') en vez de con Javascript.

Comment: Amigo, creo que es problema con el .htaccess, debido a que hoy abro mi proyecto y me bota un 500 Error Server, y cuando renombro el htaccess por htaccess_old no me sale el error 500.

Comment: Eso del error 500 no es lo que has contado en tu pregunta, amigo. Idependientemente del error 500, que es algo nuevo, tienes el problema que he descrito. Seguro.

Comment: Si, el error persiste.